# How do I create a view on data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 13 fields including:

```
Computer, Application
```

I need to have a similar table/view that lists COUNT(Application) along with Application listed only once for each Computer. All fields must exist with the addition of the new field.

I need something similar to:

```
Computer| Application | AppCount | ...
USD9090   MS Outlook   3 
UOD0909   MS Outlook   5
UDL4563   Skype        4
```

Ive tried grouping by Computer with Application COUNT

```
SELECT TOP 5 Computer, ComputerID, Application FROM AppReliability WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT TOP 5 Count(Application) AS App, Computer
FROM AppReliability
WHERE Date >= DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE())
GROUP BY Computer
ORDER BY App DESC)
```

I cant get the correct output

Comment: "I need to have a similar table/view that lists COUNT(Application) along with Application listed only once for each Computer." _So each computer can have multiple applications, yes? SO how do you determine which application to show for each computer?_

Comment: A Computer can have multiple applications

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want an aggregation query?

```
select Computer, Application, count(*) as AppCount
from AppReliability
group by Computer, Application;
```

Your question doesn't mention anything about dates or why you would be using `top (5)`.

Comment: Yes I have 2 date fields

Comment: The ultimate end product needs top 5 but for now I need a complete table